# IntelliJ find usage no longer prompting to search for base method instead

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have used IntelliJ for many projects and recently, when I try to find usages of an overridden method by pressing <kbd>ALT+F7</kbd>, it usually brings up a prompt asking if I want to search for the base method instead.

It is no longer doing that.

Is there an option to re-enable that back?  I don't remember if there were any recent plugins or updates installed that disabled this.

Comment: Did you search in the settings search box?

Comment: Yes I couldn't find any options for find usages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem.  There was a plugin called Gauge that was installed and a month ago, they released a version that "enhanced find usages functionality".  I disabled that plugin, restarted IntelliJ and I have my find usages back to normal!  I don't remember installing this plugin and I don't think I need it or use it.  It is possibly a plugin that came with IntelliJ.  Nevertheless, that was the cause of the issue.

Comment: Was it installed by default by IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> should show the prompt.

See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-usages-method-options.html

> When you search for usages of a method implementation with this dialog Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F7, IntelliJ IDEA will ask whether or not you want to search for the base method. With any other find usages actions such as Alt+F7 or Ctrl+Alt+F7, the base method will be included in the search results automatically.